# Do Google Analytics offer a end-user opt-out option?

Tags: mobile, google-analytics

I am wondering if `Google Mobile Analytics` offer an `opt-out` option for end users to not have their data collected, and if so where can I get more info on it?

Comment: I suspect that is something that the individual website has to offer.  The website GA Code has no idea who you are. If you the user where going to have the option of opting out you would have to be logged in to the website so that Google Analytics knew it was you.

Comment: Are you a developer who looks how to implement this (because there is documentation on this) or are you and end user yourself (in which case you have to look if the website/app offers an opt-out facility - this, while possible and in some jurisdictions required,  is something that needs to be implemented by the developer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They dont offer an opt-out approach. If you would like to opt out of being tracked, you can use browser extensions such as 'Ghostery' to disable tracking on sites.

Visitors are seen as consenting to data collection methodologies and privacy policies by their continued use of a website.